# ADFS Persistent ID Mapping Store

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs

Where does ADFS store persistent identifiers for a relying party trust once the NameId outgoing name ID format has been set to Persistent Identifier?  Our setup is using WID for the ADFS database.  I checked the tables using SQL Management Studio and haven't found any trace of that mapping for users to persistent ADFS Id after they first login with SSO and the persistent id gets created.

This is the Rule that we have setup on the Relying Party Trust to make the UPN the persistent identifier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is dynamically computed by AD FS using a built-in attribute store that is not exposed. It used to be explained at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2010/02/17/name-identifiers-in-saml-assertions.aspx but since the blogs were migrated the link currently doesn't work.

I am trying to get the content republished. If I succeed I will update this post.

Comment: Thanks for trying to resurrect that link for me.  Looking forward to seeing what it says about the persistent attribute store in ADFS.